# Computer parts are made with 90% success. Determine the distribution for the case of 4 units.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am encountering distributions for the first time.

I refer to the probabilities that a computer part is made successfully/unsuccessfully as $\Pr(A) = 0.9$ and $\Pr(\overline{A}) = 0.1$ respectively.

The edge cases seem intuitive, i.e no working parts contained in a set of 4 would be would be $\Pr(\overline{A}) \cdot \Pr(\overline{A}) \cdot \Pr(\overline{A}) \cdot \Pr(\overline{A}) = 0.1^4$

As per my post history, it is rare for me to post a question without including "progress so far", but here I am having difficulty understanding what kind of probabilistic distribution should be applied. It seems that the problem should in some way be related to binomial distribution...

any tips/links/literature/assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: It is indeed binomial distributed: $Pr(X = k) = {4\choose k}0.9^k(1-0.9)^{4-k}$ In your example $k=0$.

Comment: @callculus thanks once more for the help. The way you phrased your comment cleared everything up. If you want to post it as an answer, i would accept it (same applies for the other post you helped with today).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For me it is not necessary to post an answer. But you can accept the answer of Sander.

Comment: @callculus I have accepted Sander's answer because it does answer the question. Nonetheless, your contributions (also to the previous question) have been most helpful in aiding my understanding of the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the success probabilities for the 4 parts are independent, then this is a case of the binomial distribution, which describes the probability of $k$ successes in $n$ trials when the trials are independent. [Link to Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)